# how to read the merged formula VLOOKUP cell value using poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, vlookup

i have an excel file with merged and formula cell which is using the VLOOKUP(B16,Data!$A$2:$C$7,3,0). In specific cell $40 is appearing as value. but when i try to read the value it is reading only 40 and skipping the $ part.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        String excelFilePath = "D:\\test\\1_sample1_UA Logo Order form update on 2016-12-06.xls";

        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                excelFilePath));
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(input);
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
        workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);

        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(3);
        Row row = sheet.getRow(15);
        Cell cell = row.getCell(7);

        for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getNumMergedRegions(); i++) {
            CellRangeAddress region = sheet.getMergedRegion(i); // Region of
                                                                // merged
                                                                // cells

            int colIndex = region.getFirstColumn();
            int rowNum = region.getFirstRow();

            if (region.isInRange(15, 7)) {

                CellReference cellReference = new CellReference("H15");
                Row row2 = sheet.getRow(cellReference.getRow());
                Cell cell2 = row2.getCell(cellReference.getCol());

                // formulla evaluato
                FormulaEvaluator forEvaluator = workbook
                        .getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
                workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator()
                        .evaluateAll();
                workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);

                CellValue cellValue = forEvaluator.evaluate(cell2);

                System.out.println("cell string value2 :: "
                        + cellValue.formatAsString());

            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: The cell value is 40 and the cell number format is currency. So the question is how to read formatted cell values from Excel using apache poi. This question is answered many times already.

Comment: i will try it..